# Enforce Observable Subscribers to only write to the stream one at a time

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, observable

I currently am using observables to manage messages being generated on bus which are being pushed over various streams.

All works well but as messages can come in, it's possible for the system to try and write multiple messages to the stream at once (i.e. messages coming in from multiple threads) or that messages are published quicker than they can be written to the stream... as you can image, this causes issues when writing.

Hence I'm trying to figure out how I can organize things so that when messages come in only one will be processed at a time. Any thoughts?

```
public class MessageStreamResource : IResourceStartup
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;
    private readonly ISubject<string> _sender;

    public MessageStreamResource(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;

        _senderSubject = new Subject<string>();

        //`All` can publish messages at the same time as it's
        //collecting data being generated from different threads
        _bus.All.Subscribe(message => Observable.Start(() => ProcessMessage(message), TaskPoolScheduler.Default));

        //Note the above hops off the calls context so that the 
        //writing to the stream wont slow down the caller.
    }

    public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/stream", async context =>
        {
            ...

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Lets party!\n");
            await context.Response.Body.FlushAsync();

            var unSubscribe = _sender.Subscribe(async t =>
            {
                //PROBLEM HERE
                //I only want this callback to be executed 
                //one at a time...

                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{t}\n");
                await context.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
            });

            ...

            await HoldOpenTask;
        });
    }

    private void ProcessMessage(IMessage message)
    {
        _sender.OnNext(message.Payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Rx then it will automatically ensure messages are processed one at a time. That's what Rx does for you.

Comment: Is there a problem with using `_sender.Synchronize().Subscribe(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this possibly can be done with [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// ...
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 1);

var unSubscribe = _sender.Subscribe(async t =>
{
    //PROBLEM HERE
    //I only want this callback to be executed 
    //one at a time...

    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{t}\n");
        await context.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
});
```

`SemaphoreSlim` is `IDisposable`, make sure to dispose of it when appropriate.

**Updated**, from the second look, [`MapExtensions.Map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337263(v=vs.113).aspx)
accepts `Action<IAppBuilder>`, so you're passing an `async void` lambda, essentially creating a bunch of fire-and-forget asynchronous operations. The `Map` call will return to the caller, while they may still be lingering around. This is most likely not what you want, is it?

Comment: So after I posted the question, I added a `SemaphoreSlim` but was hoping there was a "native" way of doing it with observables.

Comment: Also re `MapExtensions.Map` my code is a bit more complex than what is listed but I was trying ton make it a little simpler for the question.

Comment: @anthonyv, if you don't like `SemaphoreSlim` you can possibly create a custom task scheduler or use `EventLoopScheduler` (which should be OK if you don't have any blocking code). My concern about `async void` lambdas remain valid. It may help if you post more of your code, at least to show how you call `app.Run`.

Comment: Here is the rest https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Prototype/blob/dev/src/Glimpse.Server.Web/Resources/MessageStreamResource.cs which is invoked via https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Prototype/blob/dev/src/Glimpse.Server.Web/GlimpseServerWebMiddleware.cs#L32-L59...

Comment: I'm by far not an OWIN expert, but that seems to be OK, besides you should use `try/finally` like I did above to make sure the semaphore gets released in case of exceptions. You may want to post it to to [SO Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) so it can get more exposure.

Comment: BTW, `await SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()` doesn't lock threads, unlike this comment might suggest: `// Only 1 thread can access the function or functions that use this lock, others trying to access - will wait until the first one released.` Rather, the thread goes back to the pool.

Comment: Thanks for your help!